# Hide UIButton from different View Controller when In App Purchase is made in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, in-app-purchase, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers, ViewController One is the main one with a button on while ViewController Two is the In App Purchase. I need to hide a button on ViewController One when the In App Purchase has been made on ViewController Two.

Please provide help in Swift Language

View Controller One button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var inAppBtn: UIButton!
```

View Controller Two:

I've dismissed the View Controller Two here but I need to take inAppBtn and put it inside here and hide it.

```
  @IBAction func continueBtn(_ sender: Any) {
                if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
                    let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
                    paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
                    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
                } else {
                    print("user unable to make payments")
        }
}
```

Comment: "I need to hide a button on ViewController One when the In App Purchase has been made on ViewController Two." Then the code you have shown is irrelevant, because that is not the code where the purchase is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try add this in your func continueBtn before dismiss in ViewControllerTwo

```
if let firstVc = self.presentingViewController as? ViewControllerOne{
    firstVc.yourButton.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the purchase situation changes (i.e. the user purchased), you should always store the fact of having been purchased in a central persistent location, such as User Defaults.

Now any view controller can check with UserDefaults in `viewWillAppear` or elsewhere, and make any necessary changes, such as hiding a button, if the user has already purchased.

(If you want the visible interface to change immediately when the user purchases, then you can *also* use the NotificationCenter to post a Notification that other view controllers can register for to hear about the change.)